# Sending signals to a process opened by proc_open()

Tags: php, signals, proc-open

We've got a utility here that's using `proc_open()` to call ssh to run commands on a remote machine. However, in some cases we need to halt the command on the remote machine but `proc_close()` and `proc_terminate()` do not cause the desired signal to be sent through to the far side of the ssh connection. SSH will generally issue a `SIGHUP` to running programs when it is terminated, but we need to send a `SIGINT` to ssh which will forward it through to the program running on the remote end.

I've googled as much as I can, and there seem to be a number of `pcntl` functions for *receiving* signals, but I have not been able to find anything about *sending* signals via PHP, let alone anything related to `proc_*` functions.

Comment: You could put a shell script on remote machine which kills the process(es) you want to kill (just pass the PID to the script, e.g. `$ myKill.sh -id NNN` ). Then just execute that script via php/ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sending signals via PHP :

```
posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGTERM);
```